# generating versioned rosinstall file from currnt workspace

Tags: rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

Is there any tool that is able to dump rosinstall with version tag from current workspace or .rosinstall file?

For example, I have following .rosinstall for my application,
http://code.google.com/p/rtm-ros-robotics/source/browse/trunk/agentsystem_ros_tutorials/rtm-ros-robotics.rosinstall
for developers to work against the trunk repositories. Then, Jenkins/Hudson server check the
build status and add the latest tag.

I would be very happy if I can freeze this set as a .rosinstall file with version tag in all repositories  so that I can commit the file to as a stable.rosinstall file  and users always be able to setup with stable set of repository versions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11771/generating-versioned-rosinstall-file-from-currnt-workspace/) by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1186 on 2011-11-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried the rosinstall argument?

```
--generate-versioned-rosinstall=GENERATE_VERSIONED
                    generate a versioned rosinstall file
```

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2011-11-02**:
Thanks! that exactly what I want. I have one wish list for that feature and create new ticket for this https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3735